# MacOS Monterey Keychain Issues after interrupting terminal process, user password not accepted by keychain access

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain, defaults, restart

Version: MacOS Monterey 12.4

I messed up while doing some keychain modifications with my terminal (I used a "resetUserPermissions" terminal command and after 3-4 hours of it running, I had to shut down my mac, interrupting the process, and now my mac is constantly spamming me with "a keychain is not found for _______", and it causes problems with my passwords (I don't stay logged in on every app)). I tried re-running the command and letting it hang for literally 24 hours but it never actually finishes.

I'm trying to fix it with Keychain Access "reset default keychains", and I'm at the following step when I do this:

[image]

However, when I type in the password for this user, it doesn't accept it. My user password works fine for every other function on my mac, but not for keychain access. I tried resetting the password in Users and Groups but it still doesn't work. Wondering how I can possibly get access to this and find the password...

I'm missing a "login" keychain, maybe that's it, but I'm not 100% sure. Here are my current keychains:

[image]

As you can see there's nothing in "Local Items" and no "login" keychain, that's probably where some of my problems are. Anyone know what to do? I'm very confused. Thank you!

Comment: I also encountered the issue of the spamming and password not being accepted.  I have a home directory stored on an external volume which was created on my old Mac running Mojave.  Attempting to use this user on my new Monterey machine lead to a near identical situation to the one you described.

Comment: the reason for the problem is the missing iCloud ID + password from the keychain. Try: restart into recovery on [Intel](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl338cf9a8/mac) or [Apple Silicon](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac). Open *Utilities>Terminal* from the menu and execute *resetpassword*. In the next window select your admin name, it will prompt to enter Apple ID and password. Enter your credentials and create a **NEW** password. After restart MacOS can’t unlock the old login keychain, create a new one via the presented options.